# Python: Should I use delegation or inheritance here?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-3.x, delegation

I am pondering if I should use inheritance or delegation to implement a kind of wrapper class. My problem is like this: Say I have a class named `Python`.

```
class Python:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def snake(self):
        """ Make python snake through the forest"""
        ...

    def sleep(self):
        """ Let python sleep """
        ...
```

... and much more behavior. Now I have existing code which expects an `Anaconda`, which is almost like a `Python`, but slightly different: Some members have slightly different names and parameters, other members add new functionality. I really want to reuse the code in `Python`. Therefore I could do this with inheritance:

```
class Anaconda(Python):

    def __init__(self):
        Python.__init__(self)

    def wriggle(self):
        """Different name, same thing"""
        Python.snake(self)

    def devourCrocodile(self, croc):
        """ Python can't do this"""
        ...
```

Of course I can also call `Anaconda().sleep()`. But here is the problem: There is a `PythonFactory` which I need to use.

```
class PythonFactory:

    def makeSpecialPython(self):
        """ Do a lot of complicated work to produce a special python"""
        …
        return python
```

I want it to make a `Python` and then I should be able to convert it to an `Anaconda`:

```
myAnaconda = Anaconda(PythonFactory().makeSpecialPython())
```

In this case, delegation would be the way to go. (I don't know whether this can be done using inheritance):

```
class Anaconda:

    def __init__(self, python):
        self.python = python

    def wriggle(self):
        self.python.wriggle()


    def devourCrocodile(self, croc):
        ...
```

But with delegation, I cannot call `Anaconda().sleep()`.

So, if you're still with me, my questions are:

A) In a case similar to this, where I need to

- add some functionality
- rename some functionality
- use "base class" functionality otherwise
- convert "base class" object to "subclass" object

should I use inheritance or delegation? (Or something else?)

B) An elegant solution would be to use delegation plus some special method that forwards all attribute and method accesses which `Anaconda` does not respond to to its instance of `Python`.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't have a common base class.

Comment: I just don't have one. I am writing on "Anaconda", "Python" and "PythonFactory" is existing code which I cannot modify. I am between to sets of existing code, and need to "adapt" one to the other.

Comment: Who is going to use your snake objects? What interface or interfaces does he expect from the objects? How are the interfaces related to each other?

Comment: The interface that "Anaconda" should provie is determined by an existing code base which I am re-implementing (trying to keep the code similar).

Comment: Is `Anaconda` supposed to also `snake()` or _only_ `wriggle()` and refuse to to `snake()` as if it weren't implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> B) An elegant solution would be to use delegation plus some special method that forwards all attribute and method accesses which Anaconda does not respond to to its instance of Python.

This is simple in Python, just define `__getattr__`:

```
class Anaconda:

    def __init__(self, python):
        self.python = python

    def wriggle(self):
        self.python.snake()


    def devourCrocodile(self, croc):
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.python, name)
```

See the Python docs on [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

Comment: Side note: The adapter design pattern seems to be an ideal solution to the problem posed in the question. It is related to delegation, but more specific. mensi's answer is a Python implementation of an adapter... although the explicit declaration of `wriggle()` in that form is unnecessary (unless its body should call `self.python.snake()`). +1 :)

Comment: @Walter That's actually what the question's source does, so assuming a minor oversight I corrected it. What remains is the question whether the `Anaconda` is also allowed to directly `snake()`, otherwise `def snake(self): raise NotImplementedError()` might be necessary (or `return NotImplemented`? Though that might cause `Python.snake` to be evaluated after all...)